# Static Member Initialization of class template

Tags: c++, templates

Please find the code below:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
template<typename T>
class A
{
    static A* self;
};

template<typename T>
A* A<T>::self = NULL;
int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

I am facing a compilation problem while initialising the static pointer. Even though so many links has said the same way (the way i initialised) but still the problem resist. Below is the compilation error.

```
"expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '*' token"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`A` is a class template, so you need to specify the template parameter when defining the pointer to it.

Instead of:

```
template<typename T>
A* A<T>::self = NULL;
```

it should be:

```
template<typename T>
A<T>* A<T>::self = NULL;
```

Within the class body, specifying the template parameter is optional, so you can write `A*` there and it will be treated the same as `A<T> *`.

Answer (score 0):

try:

`template<typename T>
A<T>* A<T>::self = NULL;`